# Generic List to String Conversion Using Gson in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

I new with Xamarin , I am trying to convert my list of generic type to single string. I can comfortably performs this task in Android using below code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Response_bean>>() {}.getType();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(response_data, collectionType);
    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    String strjsonarray = jsonArray.toString();
```

But I cant found its replacement in Xamarin.
Please help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As Alessandro Caliaro said, [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) can help you.

```
List<Product> list = new List<Product>();

Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

Product product2 = new Product();
product2.Name = "Banana";
product2.Expiry = new DateTime(2010, 12, 28);
product2.Sizes = new string[] { "Big" };

Product product3 = new Product();
product3.Name = "Pear";
product3.Expiry = new DateTime(2012, 12, 28);
product3.Sizes = new string[] { "Huge" };

list.Add(product);
list.Add(product2);
list.Add(product3);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

#### Output

```
[
 {"Name":"Apple","Expiry":"2008-12-28T00:00:00","Sizes":["Small"]},
 {"Name":"Banana","Expiry":"2010-12-28T00:00:00","Sizes":["Big"]},
 {"Name":"Pear","Expiry":"2012-12-28T00:00:00","Sizes":["Huge"]}
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.